# Refresh datatable while adding new parameter

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a search screen where the user can customize what data is retrieved for the report.  These parameters are passed to datatables and then the report is retrieved through ajax.

The url used for the ajax load may be something like `report.php?batch=1&id=5`.

What I want to do is provide a link that will allow the user to download the results of the report.  To do that, I want to submit the same request to the server, but then I will just send the view to CSV instead of HTML.  To do this, I want to append an additional variable to the url, so it comes out with something like `report.php?batch=1&id=5&output=download`.

I have tried a couple of approches to add that variable, both without success.  FYI, I have assigned the datatable configuration to a variable called fixTheHeader.

1) try to set the value with fnServerParams. `fixTheHeader.push({"output":"download"});` and then reload the table with `fixTheHeader.fnReloadAjax();`.  Although this didn't generate any errors, it also didn't add the variable to the url.

2) retrieve the url set as the ajax source url using

```
    var source = $(fixTheHeader'.$classNameToAppend.').parents(".dataTables_wrapper").find("table:first").dataTable().fnSettings().oInit.sAjaxSource;
```

then append `&output=download` to `source` and redirect the window.  The issue with this approach was `?batch=1&id=5` was no longer part of the url.

I'm not picky about what approach makes it work, but, is there a way within datatables to get the url + variables, add an additional variable, and then resubmit to the server without a page reload?  I do not want to hardcode this url with parameters as I would like this same code to be able to be used for multiple reports.  I hope that makes sense.

I am using the current version (1.9.4) of datatables (http://datatables.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add download links (csv, pdf) to any dataTable using the **[TableTools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/)** extra.

Example initialization with TableTools:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am already aware of TableTools.  I do not like how it requires a .swf to be used, which is why I am interested in a different approach.